# getSymbols.yahoo returns just the symbol name without any data

Tags: r, quantmod, yahoo-finance

I am trying to download some stocks data but the quantmod functions don't seem to work. For example:

```
getSymbols.yahoo("F",env= globalenv(), return.class = 'xts',
                                       from = "2017-01-01",
                                       to = Sys.Date())


 [1] "F"
```

The package is upadated, as well as the local date set = Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C"). I also tried with getSymbols.google but it doesn't work neither and to change the return class.

Answer (score 2):

`getSymbols()` currently (as-of 0.4-10) loads the data into an environment, just like the `load()` function.  In quantmod 0.5-0, it will return the data, like `read.table()` and most other functions.

If you want `getSymbols()` to return the data, you can set `auto.assign = FALSE`.

```
Data <- getSymbols("F", from = "2017-01-01", to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Also note that you should not call `getSymbols.yahoo()` directly (as it says in `?getSymbols.yahoo`).

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Now if you want to see the historical data just type `F`:

```
> head(F)
           F.Open F.High F.Low F.Close F.Volume F.Adjusted
2017-01-03  12.20  12.60 12.13   12.59 40510800   12.22555
2017-01-04  12.77  13.27 12.74   13.17 77638100   12.78876
2017-01-05  13.21  13.22 12.63   12.77 75628400   12.40034
2017-01-06  12.80  12.84 12.64   12.76 40315900   12.39063
2017-01-09  12.79  12.86 12.63   12.63 39183400   12.26440
2017-01-10  12.70  13.02 12.66   12.85 58703500   12.47803
```

Comment: It is the first time I see something like this. The other times (e.g. with read.table ecc) it opens the object directly.
I thought it was returning me just the character "F".
Thank you very much !

Comment: Well, there are many ways of using `getSymbols()`. In this particular case you have to type in the code of the stock that you are after. Btw, feel free to accept my answer :))